# how to pass the data from one view page to another view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have two views each view have a separate form elements. I have `id` in first view page and in second view page I need to get  another value like a loyalty points both id and loyalty point should be inserted in single table.

**First view page**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
      //form data
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_category = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($category as $row)
      {
        $options_category[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
      }

      //form validation
      echo validation_errors();

      echo form_open('admin/service/add', $attributes);
      ?>
    <fieldset>

    <legend><p>General</p></legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Service id:</label>

              <input type="text" id="" name="id" value="<?php echo set_value('id'); ?>" >
              <!--<span class="help-inline">Woohoo!</span>-->

             </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Service name:</label>

              <input type="text" id="" name="service_name"  title="enter a valid name only characters are allowed" value="<?php echo set_value('service_name'); ?>" >

          </div>
          <?php
          echo '<div class="control-group">';
            echo '<label for="category" class="control-label">Category</label>';
            echo '<div class="controls">';
              //echo form_dropdown('manufacture_id', $options_manufacture, '', 'class="span2"');

              echo form_dropdown('category', $options_category, set_value('category'), 'class="span2"');

            echo '</div>';
          echo '</div">';
          ?>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here I get my `id`. My next view is given below.

**Second view**

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
      //form data
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_category = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($category as $row)
      {
        $options_category[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
      }

      //form validation
      echo validation_errors();

      echo form_open('admin/service/add', $attributes);
      ?>
    <fieldset>

    <legend><p>General</p></legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Service id:</label>

              <input type="text" id="" name="id" value="<?php echo set_value('id'); ?>" >
              <!--<span class="help-inline">Woohoo!</span>-->

             </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Service name:</label>

              <input type="text" id="" name="loyalty_point"   value="<?php echo set_value('loyalty_point'); ?>" >

          </div>
 <div class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
            <button class="btn" type="reset">Cancel</button>
             <a  href="add1" class="btn btn-success">Next page</a>
          </div>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I click save here in this page both the `id` and `loyalty_point` be stored in a table. How to do this?. Can someone help me code?

Comment: In the second view page, you already have two separate field called id and loyalty_points. Why do you think you need to pass id from the first page to the second page? I am still unable to understand.

Comment: Id field is hidden element. That id in second view must be displayed automatically in that input box, I need that id value from first page.

Comment: Ok, why don't to send the ID from first view page to a controller function, then load the second view page in the same controller function. As such you can pass the value from the controller to the second view page.

Comment: i need to send all data which means the data in first view and second view at a single button click action that is only in second view page. That is what I need

Comment: Instead of loading the whole page you can have both the views in a single view and use div hide & show or tabs so that you will get all values on single button click

Comment: I am having more than 5 views like tab menu. How to do with div. can you give me some code snippet?

Comment: Store it in session or in flash session. That way you would have those on next request (page).

Comment: I have less idea about session.How to store data and send to next view?

Comment: save data in session 
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
                            'id'       => $id,
                            'other_info'      => $other_info,
                    ));

Comment: get session data on other page $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php '<h3>View One</h3>';?>
<?php $data['hello'] = 'world'; $this->load->view('my/view/file/name',$data);?>

my/view/file/name.php

<?php echo $hello;?>
```

Comment: can you please brief it?

Answer (score 0):

There no way to do this directly,

Instead you can do as below

call first controller from first view and pass form data to second view.

On second view you can create hidden inputs and set their values from controller data.

Now submit the second form to final controller and you will get all the values of both form.

Hope this helps you.